# Redirect back to facebook app after accepting/denying permissions loop

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to figure out a way to redirect back to facebook page where app is, after user interaction with permissions (accepting or denying doesn't matter).

I've tried and read about the redirect_uri (facebook sdk, php) and used it. The problem is that I do not understand how to redirect ONCE when the user has finished interacting with app permissions.

```
if(!empty($signedRequest) && !empty($signedRequest['page']['id'])){
$page = $facebook->api($signedRequest['page']);
}
else
{
echo '<script>top.location.href = "'.$loginUrl.'"</script>';
}
//$redirect_uri = $page['link'] . '?sk=app_' . $facebook->getAppId() .'?ref=ts';

$redirect_uri =  "my_facebook_page_where_app_is";

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
'scope' => 'publish_actions',
'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri
));
```

This works and redirects back of course. But it loops..... forever.
I can't get the concept of how to redirect just once. Any help?

Comment: Why do you base the decision to redirect to the login dialog on the signed_request?

Comment: Well that's the problem. I can't figure when to redirect back to application page. So I've putted it now in there just to show my problem.

Comment: Well you could just put a GET parameter into the `redirect_uri` … and if that is set, meaning the user has been redirect back from the login dialog, react to it…

Comment: hmm not sure I'm following you. If I redirect the first time, the app reloads, checks if signed_request and redirects again because it is signed and it loops. The other solution I can think is to use facebook-sdk js, and give it a try with pop up windows and ajax.

Comment: I already implied that just checking for the presence of the `signed_request` is not helpful …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['signed_request']))
{
   // User has already authorised your app
}
else
{
   header('Location:'.$redirect_uri);
}
```

Comment: That's not true. Within a page tab app, you get a signed_request posted to your app on inital load regardless of whether the user authorized your app already or not.

Comment: Can you help then? To solve the initial problem? Because with this piece of code I can do it.